# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

So first, I've checked its radius and made sure it converges, $R = 1$.
Then, I diffrentiated nad got to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}$. I used than $ m = n - 1$. and got to $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^{m}x^{m}$.

I want to find $a_1, q$. Will $a_1$ be found by using $m=0$ , thus $a_1 = 1$, and $q = \frac{-x}{1} = x$. If so, I'll get finally to $ln(x+1)$.

**Question:** I'm just not sure about the $a_1$ part. do I use $m = 0$ to find it?

Comment: $-x/1\ne x$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $a_n$ refers to the $n$th term of the series, right?  So $a_1$ would be the first term.  That's why you plug in $m=0$, or $n=1$, into the summand.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^{n-1}\implies \frac{(-1)^{1-1}}1=1=a_1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint Consider the taylor expansion of $\ln (1-x) $

Comment: That is not the question

Comment: So expanding gives you $a1=1$